# Is there a command to see the data returned from program?

Tags: command-line, python, output

For instance, if I run a python program in the terminal like so:

```
python test.py
```

Say test.py returns an array of ints. Is there a command I can run after running the program to see this array that was returned?

Comment: No. When the interpreter completes the python script, all references to memory use are deleted, and the memory block itself is returned to the Operating System for re-use.

Answer (score 0):

If scrolling back in the terminal's slider is not what you want, you could re-run the `python test.py` and capture the output like this:

```
script test.py.log
python test.py
exit
```

or

```
python test.py |& tee test.py.log
```